# USB debugging turns off without USB connection

Tags: android

I'm trying to test my application on huawei kob-l09, I turned on developer mode( taped 7 times on build number) and Developer options menu is visible to me, but:

1. I can't turn on USB debugging - it keeps switching to off when I leave options.
2. I can't connect over ADB, it keeps saying that device is offline( probably because USB debugging turns off automatically)
3. I'm not sure if this relevant, but I can't create a temp file on this device, I get:

> java.io.IOException: Unable to create temporary file

which is the reason why I started testing this device.

Edit: temp file is irrelevant it failed to create file because I used ':' char in  file name

Comment: On my P20 Pro I do these steps: 
1. System>> About>> click Buld num 7 times
2. System>> Developer options>> [ON] Developer options & [ON] Stay awake & [ON] Allow USB Debugging >> OK

Comment: This sounds like a device/manufacturer specific issue. Did you try looking for related settings in the developer settings screen? Maybe revoke all USB-debugging authorizations and then reconnect?

Comment: `adb` is a program like any other, therefore it can also crash. I assume this is what happens in your case. Therefore only two options for you: Check for system updates and/or try a factory reset. If it still crashes after a factory rest something is wrong with the system image (e.g. manipulated by malware) or Huwaei published a defect system image.

Comment: I also needed to turn on `Allow ADB Debugging in charge only mode` - as when I first connected my phone I clicked "charge only" when given the three options.  After doing so USB Debugging stayed on and `adb devices` showed correctly.